# Firestore nested collections without AutoId! How to create with code?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

what I am trying to achieve is this hierarchy:

```
Parents (#collection)
|__ParentInfo (#document with provided ID from code, not Firestore AutoId)
   |__Children (#collection)
      |__Child1.Info (#document with provided ID from code, not Firestore AutoId)
      |__Child2.Info
      |__...
```

With my code, I have reached the point to Children sub collection:

```
Parents (#collection)
|__ParentInfo (#document with provided ID from code, not Firestore AutoId)
   |__Children (#collection)
      |__null <--- this is where the problem is
```

this is the code that I am using:

```
final _applicantsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('parents');
final doc = await _applicantsRef.document('$parentId').get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      _applicantsRef.document('$parentId').setData({
        'name': '$fatherName',
        'email': '$email',
        'reasonOfVisit': '$reasonOfVisit',
      }).then((_) {
        if (children.length > 0) {
          children.forEach((child) {
            _applicantsRef
                .document('$parentId')
                .collection('children')
                .document('${child.Id}')
                .setData({
              'name': '${child.name}',
              'kinship': '${child.kinship}',
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

How can I achieve `collection('parents').document('parentId).collection('children').document(child1)`?

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like collectionGroup:  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

Comment: @StefanoSaitta thank you for the reply, yes this is exactly what I am looking for, however, I do not understand where the problem is with my code, why is it not writing the values for the children? it is writing parents info and creating the children sub collection, but not writing the child info for each child :(